# Paypal multiple business name?

Tags: paypal

Paypal multiple business name ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

I have 3 business but, I want to use 1 paypal business account (that easy to manage)
then i want to use 3 business name, Can i do that ?

thank for every ans. ^^

Comment: Is this related to any code you are writing? If yes, please post the code where you have issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PayPal, not computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create two additional free Business Standard accounts and have your PayPal Account Manager assist with grouping them as Child accounts to your existing Parent account.  In doing so they will all pass the funds received into the same bank account.

Another advantage of doing this is that you can maintain custom branding for each of the sites/carts you are integrating your unique PayPal Accounts to.  This allows you to not only use a unique Business Name but also a Business Logo which will appear more professional to your customers.